# how can I defrag my hard drive that is hidden behind an intel optane front end. I am running 100% disk usage most of the time

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, optane

I am running windows 10 with an Intel Optane+932GBHDD drive. It used to work fine but now I am at 100% disk usage most of the time and any application that uses the disk just drags.  All the disk checking utilities say everything is A-OK.  But they are looking at the Optane front end.  I am not allowed to defrag the hard drive because the operating system things I have a terrebyte of SSD which I don't.  Can this situation be fixed?

Comment: You can likely force a defrag through `contig` or it's GUI front end, Power Defragmenter

Comment: First, if you are near 100% disk usage, you **cannot** effectively defragment it. There must be sufficient drive space to move files, which are temporarily duplicated. Second, an SSD should **not** be defragmented. See https://www.crucial.com/articles/about-ssd/should-you-defrag-an-ssd , Remove some data and leave room.

Comment: Based on the post, it is safe to assume that 'disk usage' refers to a resource issue where the disk 'utilization' is spiking to 100%.   This is different than disk space.  Also, there are a lot of old threads related to Intel Optane Memory and high disk utilization.  Typically they have pointed to software/drivers issues or failing hdd's.  OP will need to do a bit more legwork to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

**Backup your system.**

Possible the drive is failing or an issue with the drivers as there were a number of changes to how Optane memory was managed (Optane Memory Manager then RST Driver).

**Backup your system.**

Follow the Intel troubleshooting steps located here:

**Troubleshooting Guide for Intel® Optane™ Memory**
https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000055140/memory-and-storage.html

**Backup your system.**

Answer (score -1):

As stated in comment. NTFS (the file system underlying windows) NEEDS to be overprovisioned to function some kind of normally.

The fix seems quite simple? Delete some junk or transfer it to another drive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are assuming a capacity issue based on a misinterpretation of the OP's reference to disk 'usage'

Comment: Quite right. Reading again it looks like "pinning/thrashing the drive" would be the correct phrase not "disk usage". Thrashing drives is a windows built-in feature since about 1999.

Comment: Disk usage is an acceptable way to describe what the OP saw. Microsoft tracks disk utilization in Task Manager unrelated to capacity, which may be where the OP got their numbers.  Can be misleading for sure.  I think itr is the most likely read based on the post.